# Re-organize namespaces according to directory structure

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I made arrangement in my solution. I made seperation of projects and reorder directories. Now my namespaces are messed up. Is there any tool that will arrange the namespaces according to the position of the file in the project?

For example, if a cs file is in Printers/Pdf directory under MyProj project, I would like the namespace of the classes in the file will be MyProj.Printers.Pdf.

***EDIT:*** I am looking for free tool if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resharper > Right click on the project > Refactor Menu > Adjust Namespaces`. This will re-arrange all namespaces according to folder structure, as it should be.

Comment: I am looking for free tool if possible.

Comment: This menu option is only available to users who have the Resharper plugin installed into Visual Studio; t is not there by default.

Comment: I disagree with the "as it should be" part. When I have a large number of files in a project, I like to use folders to organize my files within one namespace. Often there's no sense in creating new namespaces for every subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper can do this, though it's commercial. But there is a trial version.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ - This plugin for Visual Studio is pretty much mandatory in mind for anyone who does development. It has some of the best refactoring options available. It is created by JetBrains, the makers of IntelliJ, which has the best refactoring options of any Java IDE out there.

Comment: @Mike Mozhaev: I am looking for free tool if possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this as well as update the using statements in all files which use those classes.

Comment: I am looking for free tool if possible.

Comment: There's a 30 day trial you can use to get things in order. Resharper is an amazing productivity tool though. You just might buy it if you try it.

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is the best option and is well worth the money. If you have paid the costs for Visual Studio, a Resharper license cost will feel like pennies.

As for free options, I think a project wide, find & replace might be your best bet. You could find what the incorrect namespace is, then folder by folder find it and replace it with the correct one. If you just moved it to a different project, you could just search for...

```
namespace MyOldProject.
```

and replace it with...

```
namespace MyNewProject.
```

This is assuming you kept directory structures.